# Azure Active Directory Password Authentication Issue from .Net App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to use Azure AD (Active Directory Password Authentication) from .Net Web App Hosted in Azure App Service. But we are getting the connection error while the app is trying to connect to Azure SQL Database.

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The function is unfamiliar with the
> Certificate Authority that generated the server's certificate.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> Exception Details: AdalException: The function is unfamiliar with the
> Certificate Authority that generated the server's certificate.
> Source Error:   An unhandled exception was generated during the
> execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
> and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
> stack trace below.   Stack Trace:
> [AdalException: The function is unfamiliar with the Certificate Authority that generated the server's certificate.]
> ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken(String username, IntPtr password,
> String stsURL, String servicePrincipalName, ValueType correlationId,
> String clientId, Boolean* fWindowsIntegrated, Int64& fileTime) +867
> ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken(String username, String password,
> String stsURL, String servicePrincipalName, ValueType correlationId,
> String clientId, Int64& fileTime) +105
> System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
> +371    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() +58    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +48   [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +4316222    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
> waitCompletionNotification) +12771596
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +34    System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClass134_1.<GetFedAuthToken>b__3() +41    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() +58    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +48

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce your issue with the same tech stack application that you have given with the below implementation:

1. Created the .NET Core 6 Web App locally and Azure App Service + SQL Database in the Azure Portal.

There are two sides you have to make some changes to achieve the requirement of Azure AD Password Authentication with the .NET Core App. One is from the Application Code and the other is from the Azure Portal Side.

I did this by following the ***TimBurris*** tutorials and Code snippet from [GitHub](https://github.com/TimBurris/DemoAzureActiveDirectory/tree/main).

**This is my application code folder structure** :

[image]

### Configuration to the Code Files:

**Index.cshtml**:

```cs
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">This is a list of Products</h1>    
    <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    
        @foreach(var product in Model.Products)
                {
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@product.ProductID</th>
                    <td>@product.ProductName</td>
                    <td>@product.Quantity</td>
                    </tr>
                }                
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**ProductService.cs**

```cs
using KamNetCoreSqlApp572.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KamNetCoreSqlApp572.Services
{

    // This service will interact with our Product data in the SQL database
    public class ProductService
    {
        private static string db_source = "<server_name>.database.windows.net";
        private static string db_user = "<user_name>";
        private static string db_password = "<password>";
        private static string db_database = "<db_name>";

        private SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            
            var _builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            _builder.DataSource = db_source;
            _builder.UserID = db_user;
            _builder.Password = db_password;
            _builder.InitialCatalog = db_database;
            return new SqlConnection(_builder.ConnectionString);
        }
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            List<Product> _product_lst = new List<Product>();
            string _statement = "SELECT ProductID,ProductName,Quantity from Products";
            SqlConnection _connection = GetConnection();
            
            _connection.Open();
            
            SqlCommand _sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(_statement, _connection);
            
            using (SqlDataReader _reader = _sqlcommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (_reader.Read())
                {
                    Product _product = new Product()
                    {
                        ProductID = _reader.GetInt32(0),
                        ProductName = _reader.GetString(1),
                        Quantity = _reader.GetInt32(2)
                    };

                    _product_lst.Add(_product);
                }
            }
            _connection.Close();
            return _product_lst;
        }

    }
}
```

**appsettings.json:**

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<copy the primary domain of your Azure AD looks like `xxx.onmicrosoft.com`",
    "TenantId": "<Azure_Tenant_Id>",
    "ClientId": "<Azure_App_Registration_ClientId>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```cs
namespace KamNetCoreSqlApp572.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }    
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Configuration in the Azure Portal:

Run the below script to create some data in the SQL database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
(
     ProductID int,
     ProductName varchar(1000),
     Quantity int
)

INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (1,'Mobile',100)
INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (2,'Laptop',200)
INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (3,'Tabs',300)
```

- Add your Client IPs in the Server Firewall of the SQL Server.

2. Go to Microsoft Entra ID - App registrations - Create New with the endpoints:

- Your Azure Web App URL: `https://kamnetcoresqlapp572.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`
- If you are running locally, then copy the application URL from the Project > Properties Folder > `launchSettings.json` to the App Registration Endpoints:

[image]

From the same App Registration menu, go to the Enterprise Application where you have to add the users as shown below:

[image]

**Result**:

1. Build the Solution and Publish it to the Azure Web App.
2. Copy the Azure Web App URL and open it in the browser, it will ask you for the user mail ID, and password and grant access like in the below screenshot:

[image]

3. Check the Consent box and Accept and it will take you to the result page defined in the Code.

[image]